# Unknown amount of vars for class function? C++

Tags: c++, function, variables

I´m trying to setup a mouse-over function for my object class, that shows some information on the top left corner.
But since all objects could possibly be different I want to make a function inside my class like this:

```
void mouseOver( number of x vars ){
  [print in the top left corner]...
  checkVarsFor(this->vars):
    case HP:
    somecode...
    case ATK:
    somecode...
    ...
}
```

In my function I want to call it somewhat like this:

```
myObj obj;
obj.mouseover(HP, ATK, POS, SPD);
myObj obj2;
obj2.mouseover(POS);
```

So I want a function inside my class that takes `1-x` variables, and the function shall print the corresponding stats.

Do i have to make x defines of 'mouseover' with `1-x` variables inside or is there a way that I can say "I have no clue how many vars this function gets, check the vars and activate all corresponding sub parts of this function".

I hope I could somewhat explain my goal and that I get some help here.
It would be enough to get a "To solve your problem look up ...".
Off curse a small non-pseudo code to help me get it even faster would be perfect.

P.s.: I use C++ and SDL2 on windows if that information helps in any way.

Comment: If different number of args mean different things, then you need to overload it. If you just want to batch process all the args then consider variadic templates

Comment: My suggestion would be to call the function multiple times with different parameters, e.g. a `for` loop, instead of having the function be adapting to multiple different cases

Comment: When they are all of same type use a vector